# How to access minicron using Nginx at specified URL

Tags: nginx, config

I've installed minicron from https://jamesrwhite.github.io/minicron/ on an ubuntu aws server with Nginx and when I don't specify a directory in location, the primary url is redirected to the Cron page as expected. However, if I add 'minicron' to the location as you see below, I get "Sinatra doesn't know this ditty" error. I'm at a lost and google hasn't been any help for either of these problems. My main goal is just to get minicron to load at a separate sub domain or directory than the main url. Any help would be appreciated.

```
http{

    ...

    server {
           # The port you want minicron to be available, with nginx port 80
           # is implicit but it's left here for demonstration purposes
           listen 80;

            # The host you want minicron to available at
            server_name *.com;

            location /minicron {
                # Pass the real ip address of the user to minicron
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

                # minicron defaults to running on port 9292, if you change
                # this you also need to change your minicron.toml config
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9292;
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently the URI `/minicron` is being sent upstream to `http://127.0.0.1:9292/minicron`. Your previous test would have hit `http://127.0.0.1:9292/`.

You need to rewrite the URI before sending it upstream. Maybe:

```
location /minicron/ {
    ...
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9292/;
}
location = /minicron { rewrite ^ /minicron/ last; }
```

See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) and [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass) for details.

Comment: The page now opens at the correct URL, but all of the links within the page are pointing to the root directory. ie, url.com/jobs should point to url.com/minicron/jobs but doesn't.